# Working with ListBox in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

am trying to set `listbox` values as selected based on the value obtained from `json`

My problem is while putting static data am getting that values as selected.

please look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/9Stxb/89/
But in the above code if my `json` data change, the above selection will not correct.this will be sometimes `val1,val2,val3` or any combination .

i used following code

but it is not working..
http://jsfiddle.net/9Stxb/91/

code

```
var myData ={
    "_id": "525f8226360cc02c2bd63dec",
    "id": "30",
    "jobs": [{
        "_id": "524a4f4cc973602da0d4ee10",
        "id": "4",
        "launch": "mypraram val url",
        "names": "val1",

    }, {
        "_id": "525f6deb360cc02c2bd63dea",
        "id": "28",
        "launch": "jithinurl",
        "names": "val2"
    }],
    "server": "180.16.17.60"
} 
$(function() {
    for(x in mydata.jobs){        $('#jobSel').val(['mydata.jobs[x].names','mydata.jobs[x].names']);
   } 
});
```

html

```
<div class="id_100">
    <select id="jobSel" class="longcombo" multiple>
        <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Psl posted answer ...have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's updated js...

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Stxb/95/)

```
var jsonData = {
    "_id": "525f8226360cc02c2bd63dec",
        "id": "30",
        "jobs": [{
        "_id": "524a4f4cc973602da0d4ee10",
            "id": "4",
            "launch": "mypraram val url",
            "names": "val1",

    }, {
        "_id": "525f6deb360cc02c2bd63dea",
            "id": "28",
            "launch": "jithinurl",
            "names": "val2"
    }],
        "server": "180.16.17.60"
}
$(function () {
    var selectedVals = new Array();

    for (var i=0;i<jsonData.jobs.length;i++) {
        console.log(jsonData.jobs[i])
        selectedVals.push(jsonData.jobs[i].names);
    }
    $('#jobSel').val(selectedVals);
});
```

Comment: In this case, you can either match it with select option's text value or can extract id from "names" and use push it in array.

Comment: how can i ge the id of names?please help